# How To Create a Scroll Back To Top Button with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I have an app that displays images using RecyclerView, I want to show a button for the user to return the top when scrolling down

Something like this:

[image]

so how can I do that?

**fragment_wallpaper.xml**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".Fragment.ImagesFragmentProject.WallpapersImagesFragment">

<!-- "descendantFocusability" to make the recyclerView not scrolls to the top itself -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_image_wallpapers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**WallpaperFragment.java**

```
public class WallpapersImagesFragment extends Fragment implements Picasso.ItemClickListener {

String[] TopImages;
private Picasso adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_images_wallpapers, container, false);

    // ArrayList for TopImages
    TopImages = new String[]{
            // 1
            "https://i.ibb.co/GWRmtzt/AL-RZAK-0bb3940f-bd1a-458d-8377-d92fbc7aa7df.jpg",
            // 2
            "https://i.ibb.co/Cb4b46W/Allah-Call-upon-me-b680792f-3870-406c-9430-014fa3ced1f2.jpg",
            // 3
            "https://i.ibb.co/WGY5Rtb/Allah-Muhammad-8ac1439d-6295-4082-9748-1a33b1008424.jpg",
            ..............
    };

    // make new object and find the view "GridView" */
    RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_image_wallpapers);
    // Calculate the items and auto-fit it on the screen
    int mNoOfColumns = HomeImagesFragment.Utility.calculateNoOfColumns(getActivity(), 140);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), mNoOfColumns));
    adapter = new Picasso(getActivity(), TopImages);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // change the adapter at random every specific time{
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(TopImages));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // get the image
    String image = TopImages[position];
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PicassoDisplayWallpaperImage.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageUrl", image);
    // to not repeat the image when click on it many times
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}

// Calculate the items and auto-fit it on the screen
public static class Utility {
    public static int calculateNoOfColumns(Context context, float columnWidthDp) { // For example columnWidthdp=180
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float screenWidthDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        int noOfColumns = (int) (screenWidthDp / columnWidthDp + 0.5); // +0.5 for correct rounding to int.
        return noOfColumns;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `FloatingActionButton` into the `RelativeLayout` as a sibling to the `RecyclerView`, adjust its position to top and center of the parent.

Then change its `backgroundTint` for your gray color (works from API-21), below API-21, it takes the `colorAccent` by default.

Add `ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24.xml` from Android assets into the drawable folder, and use it in the FAB's `android:src` attribute.

To scroll to the top of the `RecyclerView` use either `scrollToPosition()` or `smoothScrollToPosition()`

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//          recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

        }
    });
```

Layout:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".Fragment.ImagesFragmentProject.WallpapersImagesFragment">

    <!-- "descendantFocusability" to make the recyclerView not scrolls to the top itself -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_image_wallpapers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#6D353232"
            android:backgroundTint="#6D353232"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24"
            app:rippleColor="#6D353232" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

You can control to hide/show the fab button by adding a custom `ReyclerView.OnScrollListener` & override `onScrolled()` & `onScrollStateChanged()` methods

```
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if (dy > 0) { // scrolling down
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before hiding the fab

                } else if (dy < 0) { // scrolling up

                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { // No scrolling 
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before hiding the fab 
                }

            }
        });
```

Here's a preview

[image]

Comment: That's a great explanation, but I have two issues, first the button "floatingbutton" scroll with the RecyclerView, second when I use the show and hide button code it does not work.

Comment: Hello @ededede thanks for the comment.. do you want the fab button to scroll along with the RecyclerView scrolling? .. for the second question how it does not work .. is there a runtime error or something

Comment: there's a little hack to change the `FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);` to `FloatingActionButton fab = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);` as you're using a fragment

Comment: Yep, I know that, but when I scroll to up it is not shown the button + when I delete "visibility" in XML the button scroll with the whole screen and not fixed as it appears to you.

Comment: Can you remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for a while and see

Comment: the same thing, I don't know that's why I used this fragment in vuepager+tablayout or something!, but But I do not think so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216309/discussion-between-zain-and-ededede).

Answer (score 4):

Is using `RelativeLayout` a requirement? This seems straightforward with a `FrameLayout` or a `ConstraintLayout` and a `FloatingActionButton`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scrollUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" <!--This line is where you set the drawable arrow icon you're using-->
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_image_wallpapers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`RecyclerView` has several helper methods and interfaces for scrolling, check the docs for all of them. The one you're looking for is [scrollToPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#scrolltoposition)

```
scrollUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
    //Position 0 since you want to scroll to the beginning of your list.
    //Might be size of the data list instead of 0, depending on how you set
    //up your recyclerview adapter
}
```

You can even have the button only visible after the user scrolls up, and hide it otherwise, with the [onScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#addOnScrollListener(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)). The listener fires anytime a scroll change is registered on the view:

```
scrollUp.setVisibility(View.GONE)
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        //dy is the change in the vertical scroll position
        if(dy > 0){
            //scroll down
            scrollUp.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
        else if(dy < 0){
            //scroll up
            scrollUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, but I have an issue, the button "floatingbutton" It is only hidden and does not appear either when scrolling up or down